# How to filter Github PRs that are merged and closed but the branch hasn't been deleted

Tags: github, filter, pull-request

After submitting a PR in Github, it gets approved and then it's merged into master. At this point I should delete my branch to keep things tidy. I'm no angel and often forget to do this!

Github has a handy Pull requests page to keep track of all your open/closed PRs. What I would like to know is, can a filter my PRs by the following:

`is:pr author:myusername is:closed is:merged` then something like `is:branchAliveYouFool`

This would show me all PRs that I've created, that are closed, that have been merged and, crucially, that haven't had the branch deleted.

I've searched through the terms that can be used but can't find what I'm looking for:
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You could use the API if you really wanted to: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests. But I don't think the website offers that feature.

Comment: ruby script: https://gist.github.com/kevinhughes27/9753852 (not written by me)

Answer (score 2):

Visiting the link: `https://github.com/"your-account"/"your-repo"/branches/yours` should show you what you're looking for.

Comment: This works for me. You can go through the list of branches and check the ones marked with a purple icon. Those are branches that have been merged but that are not deleted. You can also do it for all branches by going to `all` instead of `yours` but if it's a large repo, you could be scrolling quite a bit because there is no filter as far as I know.